# element ui upload component not sending stream data

Tags: upload, element-ui

**Image Upload using el-upload component**

I am getting 204 no content response from the server

```
   el-upload(
        action="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/stage.greenausm.com",
        :mulitple="false",
        :data="xhrData"
        :show-file-list="false", :on-success="handleAvatarSuccess",
        :before-upload="beforeAvatarUpload",
      )
```

The request  to the server does not have the image data

------WebKitFormBoundaryksB7UzZHz8SWLdPk
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="img.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

------WebKitFormBoundaryksB7UzZHz8SWLdPk--

How can I get the component to send image data

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem i worked around it using form data. I set the auto-upload  attribute to false then passed a custom http request

```
<el-upload  drag action="" :data="fileList"   :http-request="uploadFiles" :auto-upload="false" :multiple="false" >
```

on the custom function to upload files I created a new formData object and handled it before uploading to the server. Here is an example

```
    uploadFiles() {
      //Create new formData object
      const fd = new FormData();

      //append the file you want to upload
      fd.append("file", this.file.raw);

      //add other data to the form data object if needed
      fd.append("data", this.data);

     //send call the api to upload files using axios or any other means
       axios.post('http://serveUrl/upload', fd);
   },
```

Comment: @GJasonSharma I have updated my answer. Please check

Answer (score 0):

```js
 handleChange(file, fileList){
                    this.fileList.push(file);
                },
```

```html
:on-change="handleChange"
:file-list="ListFiles"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).